# how to get post id GRAPH API facebook

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

how can i find the post_id value for steam table in fql.GRAPH API.i tried something like this:

```
SELECT like_info FROM stream WHERE post_id ='$id'
```

but as you can see there is an error:
Click [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B63GOnae39s1VEZpVHlGMjc2MWs/edit?usp=sharing) to see

please tell me how can i get post_id in stream table in order to find like_info field.Comment if further info required.thanks

Comment: Question seems to be misleading. You are saying- `how can i find the post_id value for steam table` and then you are quering `like_info` with the `post_id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the length of `post_id` is quite big since it includes both userId and objectID. So, while making the query you should provide the `post_id` in the `quotes`. The code seems to be fine, but in the example link you shared, the id is not in quotes

[Working Example](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20like_info%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20post_id%3D%22POST_ID_HERE%22)